# CSS Psuedo Selector And Combinator

Tags: css

```
label:before > input:not(:checked) {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 3px;
   width: 45px;
   height: 22px;
   border-radius: 23px;
   border-color: #3089cb;
}
```

How come that will not work?

Comment: This won't work, as you can't target an element with the pseudo element like that. Explain what you want it to do? ... Maybe with a markup

Comment: Create a before and after psuedo element. Within a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap those element selecors for it to work, and as well remove the immediate child selector `>` and use i.e a sibling selector `+`

```
input:not(:checked) + label:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 3px;
   width: 45px;
   height: 22px;
   border-radius: 23px;
   border-color: #3089cb;
}
```

And here with a markup sample

```css
label {
   position: relative;
}
input:not(:checked) + label:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 45px;
   height: 22px;
   border-radius: 23px;
   background: #3089cb;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<label></label>
```

Comment: I don't have access to modify how the CMS works at uCoz - that's not an option :(

Comment: @NazarMaksymchuk And what does that mean? ..What can't you change?

Comment: I dont have access to it's source code - closed system; its not like wordpress.

Comment: @NazarMaksymchuk So doesn't my answer help to solve it then?

Comment: yes - but your first comment explained the problem to me.
I know I can simply do label:before

Comment: @ LGSon I wanna ask a question to my knowledge, why used  `:not` when it can be work with only `:checked`

Comment: @LokeshGupta I didn't change the OP's original per element selector, I simply swapped the 2 to show the order they need to be in. The `input:not(:checked)` is not the same as `input:checked`, `input` is.

Comment: @LGSon can you explain the `:not` how can we use it.